# How to extend the data type of Sequelize (v5)?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I try to do it like the official documentation.
  https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/data-types.html#extending-datatypes

But it seems that the toSql function is not called.

What am i doing wrong?

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

function sequelizeAdditions(Sequelize) {
  const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;
  class NEWTYPE extends DataTypes.ABSTRACT {
    toSql() {
      console.log("run toSql -------------");
      return "INTEGER(11)";
    }
  }

  DataTypes.NEWTYPE = NEWTYPE;

  DataTypes.NEWTYPE.prototype.key = DataTypes.NEWTYPE.key = "NEWTYPE";
  Sequelize.NEWTYPE = Sequelize.Utils.classToInvokable(DataTypes.NEWTYPE);
};

sequelizeAdditions(Sequelize);

const db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./db.sqlite"
});

const table = db.define("test", {
  data: {
    type: Sequelize.NEWTYPE
  }
});

table.sync({alter: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bug (as of version 5.21.5).
I found a temporary solution here. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11177#issuecomment-596244206

A working example:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const { classToInvokable } = require('sequelize/lib/utils/classToInvokable');

function sequelizeAdditions(Sequelize) {
  const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;
  // Note here
  const ABSTRACT = DataTypes.ABSTRACT.prototype.constructor;

  class NEWTYPE extends ABSTRACT {
    toSql() {
      console.log("run toSql -------------");
      return "INTEGER(11)";
    }
  }

  DataTypes.NEWTYPE = NEWTYPE;

  DataTypes.NEWTYPE.prototype.key = DataTypes.NEWTYPE.key = "NEWTYPE";
  Sequelize.NEWTYPE = Sequelize.Utils.classToInvokable(DataTypes.NEWTYPE);
};

sequelizeAdditions(Sequelize);

const db = new Sequelize({
  dialect: "sqlite",
  storage: "./db.sqlite"
});

const table = db.define("test", {
  data: {
    type: Sequelize.NEWTYPE
  }
});

table.sync({alter: true});
```